# Android emulator screen resolution problem

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-layout

I want to create a android application with API 1.6 and for the android mobile 240x400 resolution. But the emulator I get is a smaller size which does not fit the application perfectly.

Comment: are you using "Scale Display to real size" flag for the emulator?

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, and you want to set the emulator resolution to 240x400, you can use command line option of the emulator `-skin 240x400` (you can set it in eclipse from: **Window -> Preferences -> Android -> Launch -> Default emulator options**)

Comment: actually when i m giving this command..emulator is opening but nt wokring al all.??

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have put the

`<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="xx" android:targetSdkVersion="xx"/>`

tag in your manifest file. This solved this issue for me.

Answer (score -1):

u need use in window manager screen resolution purpose display the items depends the screen size u r using small devices u r problem not fit in to screen

```
wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
if(wm.getDefaultDisplay().getOrientation() == 0)
{
/* if window Height is greater than 480 (Droid mobile)*/
if(wm.getDefaultDisplay().getHeight()==400 )
{
u r items insetion code write here 
}
}
```

this code is help full

Comment: Actually the layout which i have made for the activity that is same as mobile layout..when i m running in emulator few inches getting less